# Matlab plot differentiate elements on the same axis

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, graph, axis

Hello i have a problem and i need help. I have to plot a graph and to differentiate elements on the same axis. On X axis i have the number of elements of different matrices. Some of them are defined positive and others are not. On Y axis i have time resolution and memory occupied. So when i plot the all thing i want to differentiate how each matrix is defined. For example red if they are positive and blue if they are not. 
The number of positives are 8 and the not positives are 9, so i can't concatenate the two arrays.
I don't even know if it's possible, and i can't draw two different graphs. 
Thank you everyone for the help.

For example i have:

```
xaxis=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
yaxis=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];
plot(xaxis,yaxis);
```

I need to differentiate somehow in the graph the elements on 1,5,6,7,8 and 2,3,4,9.

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear. Try reframing it or maybe add a sample data or an example of what the plot needs to look like!

Comment: Yes sorry i will edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can simply use `hold` to plot both datasets in different colours, on the same figure. That is what I suppose you are trying to do!